# VB.NET - ShowInTaskBar doesn't work with a theme

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, forms

I use a theme on a form in VB.NET.

When I use my skin theme (which replaces the classic design of my form), it completely covers my form. I also use a custom `ControlBox` to manage my FormClosing buttons.
But, when I use my custom theme, the property **"ShowInTaskBar"** doesn't work correctly.

In the properties of my form, ShowInTaskBar is `"True"`. I also added `Me.ShowInTaskbar = True` in the load.
But for some reasons when I debug my App, sometimes the icon doesn't appear...

I try to add `Me.ShowInTaskbar = True` in a timer, on click, on evident event, in my skin code...

When I tried: `If Me.ShowInTaskbar = False Then...` but for my form, ShowInTaskBar is True, but it's not ...

Do you have any idea?

Note: When my custom theme is not active, ShowInTaskBar works correctly.

Comment: Is this a commercial/shareware/community skin product, or one you've created yourself?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply. It's a shareware skin, with some modifications. I can share the skin code if needed.